# Best way to keep the first and last rows in a group where a substring is present in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame on the following format

```
   Event     |   Start Time      |   ID
Type 1 - A       2020-02-03           1
Type 1 - B       2020-02-04           1 
Type 2 - A       2020-02-05           1
Type 1 - C       2020-02-06           1
Type 2 - B       2020-02-07           1
Type 2 - C       2020-02-08           1
Type 1 - D       2020-02-09           1
Type 1 - A       2020-02-03           2
  ....             ....             ....
```

I want to keep all events of "Type 1" but only include the first and last events of "Type 2" while grouping by ID.

So here for ID 1 I would want the output to be

```
   Event     |   Start Time      |   ID
Type 1 - A       2020-02-03           1
Type 1 - B       2020-02-04           1 
Type 2 - A       2020-02-05           1
Type 1 - C       2020-02-06           1
Type 2 - C       2020-02-08           1
Type 1 - D       2020-02-09           1
Type 1 - A       2020-02-03           2
  ....             ....             ....
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Your input and output seems to be exactly the same. but if you want to keep rows intact, try slicing the dataframe and then apply the groupby on the sliced dataframe

Comment: In dataframe 2, row "Type 2 - B" is removed because it's not the first nor the last Type 2 event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is create mask by [`Series.str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html), replace not matched values to `NaN`s by [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) and then get first and last values by [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) chained by `|` for bitwise `OR` with original inverted mask for not matched rows by `mask`:

```
mask = df['Event'].str.startswith('Type 2')

s = df['ID'].where(mask)
df1 = df[~s.duplicated() | ~s.duplicated(keep='last') | ~mask]
print (df1)
        Event  Start Time  ID
0  Type 1 - A  2020-02-03   1
1  Type 1 - B  2020-02-04   1
2  Type 2 - A  2020-02-05   1
3  Type 1 - C  2020-02-06   1
5  Type 2 - C  2020-02-08   1
6  Type 1 - D  2020-02-09   1
7  Type 1 - A  2020-02-03   2
```